# Error: "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'RootViewController'" in delegate header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got a delegate setup (of course) and I'm trying to reference it directly in one of my controller, but if I include the header file for my delegate (which works already) I get an error:
Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'RootViewController' in my delegate header.

Here are the lines of code that error (in SurveyClientAppDelegate.h):

```
@interface SurveyClientAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    RootViewController *rootViewController;
}
```

So, to clarify, everything works until I use this in one of my controllers:

```
#import "SurveyClientAppDelegate.h"
```

If anyone needs more of my code to help me, I'd be more than happy to post.
I'd just hate to have an overwhelming question with tons of excess code and not get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does you app delegate import RootViewController? Does it have this in the header?
`#import "RootViewController.h"`

If so, get rid of it and add `@class RootViewController;` in it's place.

EDIT: Then place the import in the .m if it's not currently there.

Comment: As I said, I had found the solution, but you almost spot on and you answered before I could answer myself. :)